# Place an image above another image without opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display an image above another image. And on hover below image the above image should display and below image opacity should change.

Now the result is, both the image is having opacity.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="contents">
            <div align="center">
                <p align="right">Sort by <select name=""><option value="">----- Select -----</option></select></p>
                <div class="items">
                    <p><img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/cg0vk7wvosjaxlji7jhr.jpg" alt="" /></p>
                    <p>Microsoft Lumia 950</p>
                    <p><span class="strike offer_price">Rs.1000/-</span> <b>Rs.500/-</b></p>
                    <hr/>
                    <p><input type="checkbox" /> Add to compare</p>
                    <div class="offer_per">
                        <p><b>50% Off</b></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="add_cart">
                        <p align="center"><img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1672/mono/32/shoppingcart.png" alt="" /></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.contents .items {
    width:24%;
    height:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #CCCCCC;
    margin:10px 0 10px 5px;
    position:relative;
}
.contents .items:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #FD6123;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.contents .items p img {
    width:100%;
}
.contents .items .offer_per {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background:#52C8D2;
    padding:5px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:12px;
}
.contents .items .add_cart {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    display:none;
}
.contents .items .add_cart p img {
    width:auto;
}
```

**jquery :**

```
    $('.items').mouseenter(function(e) {
        $('.add_cart').show();
    });

    $('.items').mouseleave(function(e) {
        $('.add_cart').hide();
    });
```

I have fiddled my code, just have a look https://jsfiddle.net/kcngmvcj/

Comment: `opacity` will be applied to all children.

Comment: @Sougata : how to avoid that.

Comment: Place the image outside `items` & set the position properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/kcngmvcj/3/

### jquery

the original was written so that when a single .items classed element was clicked all .add_cart classed elements on the page were being shown/hidden while the opacity would apply only to the single hovered .items (as per the css)

changed this..

```
    $('.items').mouseenter(function(e) {
         $('.add_cart').show();
    });

    $('.items').mouseleave(function(e) {
        $('.add_cart').hide();
    });
```

to this..

```
    $('.items').mouseenter(function(e) {
         $(this).find('.add_cart').show();
    });

    $('.items').mouseleave(function(e) {
        $(this).find('.add_cart').hide();
    });
```

..to work on multiple .items blocks

### css

replace this..

```
.contents .items:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #FD6123;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

with this..

```
.contents .items:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #FD6123;
}
.contents .items:hover img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.contents .items:hover .add_cart img {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

`.contents .items:hover` was adding opacity to everything within `.items` above code targets more specifically and separates that red box shadow border from the equation.

Lots of ways to go about it including css only options.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcngmvcj/1/)**

Like @Sougata suggested in the comment you could put the image outside of `items` div and change the position using css attributr `margin-top` :

```
<div class="contents">
    <div align="center">
        <p align="right">Sort by <select name=""><option value="">----- Select -----</option></select></p>
        <div class="items">
          <p><img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/cg0vk7wvosjaxlji7jhr.jpg" alt="" /></p>
          <p>Microsoft Lumia 950</p>
          <p><span class="strike offer_price">Rs.1000/-</span> <b>Rs.500/-</b></p>
          <hr/>
          <p><input type="checkbox" /> Add to compare</p>
          <div class="offer_per">
            <p><b>50% Off</b></p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="add_cart" style='display: none'>
      <p align="center"><img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1672/mono/32/shoppingcart.png" alt="" /></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And set the `margin-top` property to `.add_cart` :

```
.add_cart{
  margin-top: -150px;    
}
```

hope this helps.

---

```js
$('.items').mouseenter(function(e) {
  $('.add_cart').show();
});

$('.items').mouseleave(function(e) {
  $('.add_cart').hide();
});
```

```css
.contents .items {
  width:24%;
  height:auto;
  display:inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #CCCCCC;
  margin:10px 0 10px 5px;
  position:relative;
 }
.contents .items:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #FD6123;
  opacity: 0.5;
     filter: alpha(opacity=50);
 }
.contents .items p img {
  width:100%;
 }
.contents .items .offer_per {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  background:#52C8D2;
  padding:5px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size:12px;
 }
.contents .items .add_cart {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  display:none;
 }
.contents .items .add_cart p img {
  width:auto;
 }

      .add_cart{
         margin-top: -150px;    
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents">
    <div align="center">
        <p align="right">Sort by <select name=""><option value="">----- Select -----</option></select></p>
        <div class="items">
          <p><img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/cg0vk7wvosjaxlji7jhr.jpg" alt="" /></p>
          <p>Microsoft Lumia 950</p>
          <p><span class="strike offer_price">Rs.1000/-</span> <b>Rs.500/-</b></p>
          <hr/>
          <p><input type="checkbox" /> Add to compare</p>
          <div class="offer_per">
            <p><b>50% Off</b></p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="add_cart" style='display: none'>
      <p align="center"><img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1672/mono/32/shoppingcart.png" alt="" /></p>
    </div>
</div>
```